# Flash, AJAX or something else for a web-based demo interface?

Tags: javascript, flash, web, demo

My company has some software which we use to acquire data and interact with some hardware. If we wanted to put a mockup on a website which allows the user to get a feel for the UI (gather some data, change some settings etc.), what are some good methods to do so?

I'm thinking either some clever javascript or flash. I've done some JS before but only to style elements of a page. I did some stuff with flash about 8 years ago and found it really fiddly.

So my questions; Are javascript/flash reasonable solutions for this or is there something better. What is likely to be the simpler/quicker route? Is there a better way to achieve the end result?

**[Edit]** The demo doesn't need real data, just some fake/dummy example stuff is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you dont require actual backend connectivity and just need some dummy data. Few days back I participated in a session on [Flash Catalyst](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashcatalyst/). By using flash catalyst, you can create functional UIs. More details you can find in their site.

If you want a demo app with actual backend connectivity, then , I think, flex/flash is good selection. If its javascript, you need to take pain of testing it in all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript/Ajax. Flash based sites and demos I find very clunky. This would be more than adequate to create a demo, it would even be possible to have it non-ajax based and have local test data within Javascript files. Although creating such a demo interface might be challenging as you have only changed the styling of the page with Javascript, as you say.

The other simpler option is just to create a video, with a voiceover, showing the system and its different features. Not only is this a nice option because it would be easy to produce, but it will also aid in tutoring the user into how to use the system and discovering useful features.

Answer (score 1):

I dont want to sound like an evangelist, but with [Adobe Flex](http://www.adobe.com/products/flex/) you can create awesome UIs practically right out of the box, and cross-platform. Check the [Flex Sample Applications](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/?view=samples) page on the Adobe website and see if it's something like that what you're looking for.

Designing an GUI in Flash might get too cumbersome, so if you don't need all the graphic/animations, that's what Flex is there for!

Comment: Gah, I wanted to give you +1 for this but SO says your post is too old :-/

Comment: I think I accidentally down-voted and then un-down-voted when I was looking at your answer which it counted as voting.